# Error in http syntax error in arduino code

Tags: http, network-programming, arduino, httpwebrequest, gsm

The function below describes a set of values from adruino shield and uno board using gps module.

I receive some errors perhaps it is in the syntax. Please ignore the line in which the error has been pointed out. I don't want people to get scared seeing a large coding.

```
void send_HTTP(){

uint8_t answer=0;
// Initializes HTTP service
answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPINIT", "OK", 10000);
if (answer == 1)
{
    // Sets CID parameter
    answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1", "OK", 5000);
    if (answer == 1)
    {
        // Sets url 
        sprintf(aux_str, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://%s/demo_sim908.php?", url);// line number :459
        Serial.print(aux_str);
        sprintf(frame, "visor=false&latitude=%s&longitude=%s&altitude=%s&time=%s&satellites=%s&speedOTG=%s&course=%s",       
        latitude, longitude, altitude, date, satellites, speedOTG, course);   // line number : 460
        Serial.print(frame);
        answer = sendATcommand("\"", "OK", 5000);
        if (answer == 1)
        {
            // Starts GET action
            answer = sendATcommand("AT+HTTPACTION=0", "+HTTPACTION:0,200", 30000);
            if (answer == 1)
            {

                Serial.println(F("Done!"));
            }
            else
            {
                Serial.println(F("Error getting url"));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println(F("Error setting the url"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println(F("Error setting the CID"));
    }    
}
else
{
    Serial.println(F("Error initializating"));
}

sendATcommand("AT+HTTPTERM", "OK", 5000);
```

}

And I get the following errors.

> Arduino: 1.7.5 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"
>
> sketch_aug22e.ino:459:13: error: missing terminating " character
>
> sketch_aug22e.ino: In function 'void send_HTTP()':
>
> sketch_aug22e.ino:460:34: error: expected ')' before ';' token
>
> Error compiling.
>
> This report would have more information with
> "Show verbose output during compilation"
> enabled in File > Preferences.

Comment: Its just an arduino bug because the problem arose because of the doubles quotes being present

Comment: I rendered other options as mentioned below but either of the things work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an uneven number of quotation marks in line 459:

> sprintf(aux_str, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://%s/demo_sim908.php?", url);

which is confusing the compiler.

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you want to do but if you are printing 3 separate strings then it may be that you do not want to 'ESC' the third string - e.g.:

> sprintf(aux_str, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\"", "http://%s/demo_sim908.php?", url);

or alternatively if you are just trying to print two strings and the 'comma' before http is just part of the string then you might just have needed to close that 'ESCed' URL:

> sprintf(aux_str, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",http://%s/demo_sim908.php?\", url);

Comment: With which corrected line is the error still coming? Can you show the exact compiler error messages also, unedited.

Comment: I tried it in different manner by substituting the differently by changing the quotes and i got the answer. thanks anyway for your esteemed help

Comment: I suppose i used this instead:                                                  sprintf(aux_str, "AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http:/" "/%s/demo_sim908.php?", url);: